# VBScript to search two Strings in a TXT

Tags: string, vbscript, wsh, text-files

i try to make a VBScript that read a txt and search for two strings and gives out **only the last results.**

String 1: **Hello123**

String 2: **Test123**

The TXT looks like this:

```
27.07.2010 09:45 ... DumDumDum ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... BlaBlaBla ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... Hello123 ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... BlaBlaBla ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... DumDumDum ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... DumDumDum ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... Hello123 ...   'This Result
27.07.2010 09:45 ... BlaBlaBla ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... BlaBlaBla ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... DumDumDum ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... Test123 ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... DumDumDum ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... Test123 ...        'And this Result
27.07.2010 09:45 ... DumDumDum ... 
27.07.2010 09:45 ... BlaBlaBla ...
```

I try something like this, but i don't know how to do this:

Read the txt with ReadALL i think and than the search part.

```
if string 1 not found then
    msgbox "nothing found"
    Goto NEXT
else
    if string 2 not found then
        msgbox "nothing found"
    else
        msgbox "found"

    End if
End if
NEXT
```

Has someone an idea and can help me?

Greetings,
matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if its not part of a bigger vbscript program and you have the luxury to download stuff, you can use a file processing tool, such as [gawk for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) eg one liner

```
C:\test> gawk "/Hallo123/{h=$0}/Test123/{t=$0}END{print h \"\n\" t}" file
27.07.2010 09:45 ... Hallo123 ...   'This Result
27.07.2010 09:45 ... Test123 ...        'And this Result
```

With vbscript, use instr() to check for each string "Hallo123" and "Test123", then if found, assign a variable to that line. At the end of file iteration, print out those 2 variables.

example searching for "Hallo"

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'File to scan
strFile = "c:\test\file.txt"
'Pattern to search for, eg Hallo
strPattern = "Hallo"
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine  
    If InStr(strLine,strPattern)>0 Then
        WScript.Echo strLine
                H=strLine
    End If  
Loop
Wscript.Echo H
```

Comment: thanks for that but i will have it in vbscript :-), because its only one part from a big script

Comment: ok thanks for the example, but my problem is how can i search for a second string after the last founded string 1? than I'm happy :-D

Comment: Do another Instr(), assign to another variable. Please try to do it yourself this time. download a copy of script56.chm at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=01592c48-207d-4be1-8a76-1c4099d7bbb9&displaylang=en and read up.

Comment: thanks for the link, i will read it...thanks...i think i have only to do a second instr() after the first one, with the second string. thats right?